# How to automate GraphQL tests with Postman

Tags: postman, api-automation

My company is moving from REST APIs to GraphQL. I'm trying to use Postman (which I'm new to) to automate some tests for the GraphQL stuff, and I'm running into issues. The manual side of Postman testing has a radio button to switch to GraphQL, but the automation framework seems to only support JSON. For example, you can automatically interpret a response as JSON with pm.response.json(), but there's no equivalent pm.response.graphql.

My Google results are turning up articles on how to manually test GraphQL with Postman, which isn't helpful to me. Is there something simple I'm missing? Or an article I can read to help me get unstuck?

Comment: An HTTP GraphQL response generally *is* JSON: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#response.

Comment: Can you add an example endpoint so that we can help you better . Unless you give a example it's hard to suggest anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://explore.postman.com/templates/1692/working-with-graphql

This is a postman example , just click try with postman and it opens up postman with collection and everything set up

You add test scripts as same like you do for rest api, there is no difference:

[image]